# How can I find a button element and click on it?

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I am trying to click on a specific color then click buy button, I find color and can click on them, but buy element can not be found. I try some locator like XPATH, CSS_SELECTOR and others.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
import time
driver = webdriver.Edge() 
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-4645665/")  

try:
    main_div = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.flex.lg\\:flex-wrap.overflow-x-auto.px-5.lg\\:px-0"))
    )
    
    child_elements = main_div.find_elements(By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.bg-neutral-000.flex.items-center\
                                            .justify-center.cursor-pointer.ml-2.px-2.lg\\:px-0.styles_InfoSectionVariationColor__pX_3M") 
    specific_value = "سفید" 

    add_to_cart= WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
        EC.presence_of_element_located((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='add-to-cart']"))
    )
    for child in child_elements:
        time.sleep(1)
        if child.text == specific_value:
            add_to_cart.click()
            break

except Exception as e:
    print("Exception:", e)
finally:
    driver.quit()
```

Comment: You have not fully explained the problem.  There are three different css selectors in the code.  Which part, specifically, is failing?

Comment: It would be better if you temporarily remove the `try/except` handling and just let the exception happen, then post that full exception message, instead of making us guess where the error is.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I rewrote and simplified your code. Since I'm assuming you might want to choose different colors, I wrote a method specifically to choose a color based on the `colorName` parameter.

```
def select_color(colorName):
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.XPATH, f"//div[./div[text()='{colorName}']]"))).click()
```

Then the main script looks like

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.wait import WebDriverWait

url = 'https://www.digikala.com/product/dkp-4645665'
driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)

colorName = "آبی کاربنی"

select_color(colorName)

wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
wait.until(EC.element_to_be_clickable((By.CSS_SELECTOR, "button[data-testid='add-to-cart']"))).click()
# do other stuff
```

This selects the provided color and adds the item to the cart.

Answer (score 0):

specific_value is not matching i believe while iterating the child elements. Hence you are not able to click the color. Try to print the child.text data and verify the specific value manually.

another solution use child.get_attribute('innerText') to get child text data.

Comment: I can not find add_to_cart element. others are correct

Comment: I try child.get_attribute('innerText') and print it, but nothing not print in terminal.